# JQuery/AJAX code error - text not displayed on typing in textbox

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have this jsp document (below). Basically, when user types in the textbox, I want to show an error if the username exists in the database/ length<5, etc.

I want these errors to be simultaneously displayed without any refresh through jQuery/AJAX. I did this but it doesn't seem to be working. Here, CheckAvailability and Success are servlets and CheckAVailability checks the existence in database.

the JSP file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#username').keyup(function() {
   var name = $('#username').val();
            $.get('CheckAvailability?username='+name,function(responseText){
                    $('#status').text(responseText);});}); 
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form id="login_form" ><input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" class="style-4" required="required" action="Success"/>
    <div id="status"> </div>
```

CheckAvailability Servlet

```
public class CheckAvailability extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement s=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
            //make connection
            String userid = request.getParameter("username");
            String arr;

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

               if (userid.equals("")) {
                    arr = "Error: User name cannot be empty";

                } else if(userid.length()<5){
               arr="Error: Username cannot be less than 5 characters.";

                }
               else
                {
                    String table="user1.app_users";
                    String p = "alpha";//database password
                    String query = "select userid from " + table + " where userid='" + userid + "'";
                    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:system/" + p + "@localhost:1521:XE";

                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                    s = conn.createStatement();
                    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();

                    if (!rs.next()) {
                        arr="UserID <b>" + userid + "</b> is available.";


                    } else {
                        arr= "Error: UserID <b>" + userid + "</b> is already in use.";
                        }
                }

                response.setContentType("text/plain");
                response.getWriter().write(arr);

    }catch (SQLException se) {
            out.println("Error ->" + se.getMessage());
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
        {
            out.println("Error ->" + ce.getMessage());
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
  }
```

But this isn't displaying anything as I type in the text box. The servlet did fire on hitting on submit. What didn't happen was that the text didn't display alongside. The code executes, no error in my IDE on that. I can't exclusively run the servlet, it gives the error: 'HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL', i.e. when I run it with parameters. I took the input inside as in, String username="user12", and that didn't run either. Can anybody point out my mistake? I'm new to jQuery/AJAX.

Comment: You haven't finished `});` of `ready`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... but even after correcting that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {                      
            $('#userid').keyup(function(event) {  
                var user=$('#userid').val();
                $.get('CheckValidity',{username:user},function(responseText) { 
                    $('#status').text(responseText);         
                });
            });
        });
```

Had to use a different JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Overrride `doGet`, because `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` doesn't have any `processRequest` method.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    writer.print("hi " + req.getParameter("username"));
}
```

[Read this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/583147/Servlets/java/processRequest-method-servlet)

Anyway.. how are you declaring your servlet? Through annotations? In web.xml? And what's the URL pattern?

**if using web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CheckAvailability Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>your.package.CheckAvailability</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CheckAvailability Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CheckAvailability</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**if using annotations:**

```
@WebServlet("/CheckAvailability")
public class Serv extends HttpServlet {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Its via web.xml, as described above.
And no, that didn't solve the problem. Overriding doGet, I mean.
The jQuery is just not getting executed. I added alerts and they don't work too.